# Using RESTful api or firebase

Tags: android, database, push-notification

I'm new to Android and want some advice please.

I need to build two Android applications.

- Android application for train travelers

  - Purpose: Sending a custom message (for assistence) to the railway guard. The railway guard will be identified on the basis of the wagon number that has been sent.
- Android application for train guards.

  - Guard must be able to login and be able to receive (realtime) messages from travelers.
    In short, this should be a one-way messaging system.

I'm used to build RESTful web application with databases. I have no idea which technologies i should use in this situation. As far i know i can't use databases such as MySQL, Oracle on Android. I've read that Firebase is an alternative for this but i'm not sure if it's the ideal solution for this kind of application.

I could build a RESTful server and make calls from the application. I guess if i do so the messages won't be received as realtime push notifications.

Any advice please?

Comment: for FCM you have to register your app in Firebase so that you can recieve push notificaitons this is the easy way but if you want to build your own server and if you are new to this field it will be difficult for you firebase is easy to implement
my advice is that you should you Firebase

Comment: Thanks Hússain, i'll try to find out how Firebase works.

Comment: your welcome @Proxi Henn if you find my comment helpful kindly upvote thanks

Comment: Firebase cloud notification with node js is what you need, careful with hosting your own app server as doze mode affects everything.

Answer (score 0):

RESTful services are hosted on a server and cater to incoming requests with a response.

> Remote notifications are handled by a remote server. Under this
>   scenario, the client application needs to be registered on the server
>   with a unique key (e.g., a UUID). The server then fires the message
>   against the unique key to deliver the message to the client
>   application via an agreed client/server protocol such as HTTP or XMPP
>   and the client displays the message received. When the push
>   notification arrives, it can transmit short notifications and
>   messages, set badges on application icons or play alert sounds to
>   attract user's attention.[21] Push notifications are usually used by
>   applications to bring information to users' attention.

[Source of above text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#HTTP_server_push)

You can understand the basics and implement it into your application. 
However, it is too much work and you really won't be gaining much.
It is much better to use Firebase and the documentation is quite good.
You need to pay as you go based on how much you are using Firebase.

A place to start: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/